# Ruby: How to rename a hash key that is an empty string?

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm getting a hash return from our API team that includes an empty key for one of the items. The response looks like this:

```
user = [
  {
    'name' : 'John Doe',
    'roles' : {
      '' : 'admin',
      'team2' : 'user'
    }
]
```

I'd like to rename the `roles['']` key to something like `roles['default']`, but I can't find a way to do so.  If I try something like this:

```
user.roles.each {|r| r['default'] = r.delete('')}
```

it returns `Can't convert String into Integer`

Is there another way to accomplish this, short of rewriting the API return (it's been made clear that is off the table).

Comment: Why your `user` variable holds an array? Doesn't that confuse you?

Comment: That is not a valid Ruby object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `each` on roles. That will enumerate all key/value pairs. When you are interested only in one pair. This should do it:

```
user.roles['default'] = user.roles.delete('')
```

### Edit

```
user = {
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'roles' => {
      ''  => 'admin',
      'team2'  => 'user'
    }
  }

user['roles']['default'] = user['roles'].delete('')

user # => {"name"=>"John Doe", "roles"=>{"team2"=>"user", "default"=>"admin"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h = user[0].roles
h.select {|k, v| k == ''}.each { h['default'] = h['']; h.delete('') }
```